# Is there any other way to view the election results on Android?

Tags: support, election, android

The [election on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/election/1) ended just now and I can't see the results on Android. In the pop-up, it says:

> #### This election ended 26 mins ago.
>
> Download the election data and use OpenSTV for Windows or macOS to audit the results.
>
> 1,452 voters were eligible, 308 visited the site during the election, 276 visited the election page, and 99 voted

I downloaded the files and opened them but don't really understand them. Is there any other option to understand the results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A staff member will soon post the detailed results of the selection, as a link to OpaVote. [Here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election/5) is a recent example. (**Update:** The online election results have been posted, and are now linked from the notice.)

The file you downloaded is the raw ballot data, so you could 'run' the election yourself, given the appropriate program to carry it out. That's a data analysis/manipulation task meant to be carried out on computers, not mobile devices. I don't exclude the possibility that there is an OpenSTV client for Android (or iOS) but I do not know of any.